# how to get only data in webscraping (without tag names)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I wrote code for a webscraping data. The idea is to scrape links and then get into each and get the same data for x elements.

So I wrote the code but:

1. Couldn't get only text from td classes (dont have much html knowledge). I get as a result: the name of td class and the middle"93203587600000" and want only the middle. The .text method doesnt work as it is soup.find_all doesnt have it. How to do that?
2. I want to export it to the excel spreadshit so I can investigate it but a table I get consists of same elements. So idea is to name each  with a name (example : name1, name2, name3) and then put different data into them in the same order. How to do that and then export to Excel?

MY CODE:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

baseURL = ""

firmy = []

for x in range(2, 3):
    r = requests.get(f"http://={x}") //comment: frame for looping through sites
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features="html.parser")
    nazwy = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-9')
    for item in nazwy:
        for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
            firmy.append(link['href'])

# testlink = ""
daneFirm = []
for link in firmy:
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features="html.parser")
    basicData = soup.find('div', class_='basicData').text.strip()
    daneFirm.append(basicData.text)

print(daneFirm)
```

---

What I get as a result is below but I want it as described. Any hints?

```
[[<td class="col-xs-8">xxx</td>, <td class="col-xs-8"></td>, <td class="col-xs-8">xxx</td>, <td class="col-xs-8"></td>, <td class="col-xs-8">xxxx</td>, <td class="col-xs-8" itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Address">
<span itemprop="street-address">KARMELKOWA 29/41 </span><br/>
                                        53-437 <span itemprop="locality">WROCŁAW</span><br/>
```

The data I need are in below html code:

```
<divclass ="basicData">
  <table id="basicDataTable">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
     <th>Status</th
     <td>Aktywna</>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<th class="col-xs-4">NIP</th>
<td class="col-xs-8">5220003782</td>
```

and about 10 x the same element. And what I need is basically in the "col-xs-8" or table body's.

Comment: Can you share the URL? Without it, there isn't much help

Comment: sure

https://krs-pobierz.pl/wojewodztwo/lubelskie?q=

the thing is to get inside https://krs-pobierz.pl/spoldzielnia-fructon-i330019 each of those and get Status KRS etc data to the excel file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this example to get data from all companies found on `https://krs-pobierz.pl/wojewodztwo/lubelskie?q=`:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://krs-pobierz.pl/wojewodztwo/lubelskie?q='
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for a in soup.select('h4 > a'):
    print(a['href'])
    s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(a['href']).content, 'html.parser')    
    if not s.h1:
        continue
    all_data.append({'Title': s.h1.text, 'URL': a['href']})
    for th, td in zip(s.select('#basicDataTable th'), s.select('#basicDataTable td')):
        all_data[-1][th.get_text(strip=True)] = td.get_text(strip=True)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Prints:

...

```
                                                Title  ...                             Podstawowa działalność
0                                SPÓŁDZIELNIA FRUCTON  ...                                                   
1      SPÓŁDZIELNIA RZEMIEŚLNICZA W BIAŁEJ PODLASKIEJ  ...       Sprzedaż hurtowa niewyspecjalizowana (4690Z)
2   STOWARZYSZENIE CHARYTATYWNE DOBRE SERCE IM. MA...  ...  Działalność pozostałych organizacji członkowsk...
3                              FUNDACJA SCENY INVITRO  ...  Działalność pozostałych organizacji członkowsk...
4              STOWARZYSZENIE PRZYJACIÓŁ RADIA LUBLIN  ...  Pośrednictwo w sprzedaży czasu i miejsca na ce...
5   TOWARZYSTWO OCHRONY DZIEDZICTWA KULTUROWEGO FA...  ...  Działalność pozostałych organizacji członkowsk...
6      EKO LM SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚCIĄ  ...                                                   
7   PRZEDSIĘBIORSTWO-PRODUKCYJNO-HANDLOWE POLEXIM ...  ...  Pozostała działalność profesjonalna, naukowa i...
8   PRISMAKE MACIEJ ŁOBODZIŃSKI, MICHAŁ ŚMIAŁKO SP...  ...     Działalność związana z oprogramowaniem (6201Z)
9   INTER GLOBO SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZIALN...  ...  Sprzedaż hurtowa sprzętu elektronicznego i tel...
10      LIMAK SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚCIĄ  ...  Sprzedaż hurtowa sprzętu elektronicznego i tel...
11   SYNTAGMA SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚCIĄ  ...                  Transport drogowy towarów (4941Z)
12    ROCHBUD SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚCIĄ  ...      Działalność agencji pracy tymczasowej (7820Z)
13  DAGOBE SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚCIĄ...  ...  Roboty budowlane związane ze wznoszeniem budyn...
14  HOTEL IMPRESSA SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZI...  ...                                                   
15  FUNDITUS SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚC...  ...  Produkcja pozostałych artykułów spożywczych, g...
16      ETRAS SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚCIĄ  ...  Roboty budowlane związane ze wznoszeniem budyn...
17    STOWARZYSZENIE NA RZECZ ROZWOJU WSI STARA DĄBIA  ...  Wynajem i zarządzanie nieruchomościami własnym...
18  MAGIC FIGURE SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZIAL...  ...  Sprzedaż detaliczna prowadzona przez domy sprz...
19  ATLASTOUR SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚ...  ...                                                   
20                           FUNDACJA AKADEMIA WIEDZY  ...  Pozostałe pozaszkolne formy edukacji, gdzie in...
21  MIĘDZYNARODOWE NAUKOWE TOWARZYSTWO WSPIERANIA ...  ...  Wydawanie czasopism i pozostałych periodyków (...
22  DEBERG INWESTYCJE SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIE...  ...                                                   
23                    FUNDACJA LABORATORIUM TURYSTYKI  ...        Działalność organizatorów turystyki (7912Z)
24    ROCHMAN SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚCIĄ  ...                                                   
25  MEDCLINIC CONNECT SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIE...  ...                                                   
26  ECO HVAC SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚC...  ...  Wykonywanie instalacji wodno-kanalizacyjnych, ...
27  USŁUGOWE PRZEDSIĘBIORSTWO BUDOWNICTWA ENERGOOS...  ...                                 Tynkowanie (4331Z)
28  WĘDZARNIA SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚCIĄ  ...   Sprzedaż hurtowa mięsa i wyrobów z mięsa (4632Z)

[29 rows x 16 columns]
```

And saves `data.csv`:

[image]

Comment: this is EXACTLY what I wanted to do. Thank You very much.
EDIT: How close was I to that..? :P

Comment: @adamek03836 Well, you did `soup.find('div', class_='basicData').text` - which will get all text from the table (unstructured). So it would be hard to construct the excel sheet from it.

Comment: Wow.. This is Just amazing. But how does it iterate throuh website?

Comment: @adamek03836 You can navigate to next page using `page=` parameter. For example `https://krs-pobierz.pl/wojewodztwo/lubelskie?q=&page=2` for page 2. Just put my script inside the loop.